# How do I send matrix params using Dispatch?

Tags: scala, http, rest, matrix, scala-dispatch

I'm using version 0.10.1 of dispatch-core and need to send matrix params to a third party REST API.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always construct the URI manually and use `url`. I don't think either Dispatch or the underlying Async Http Client library provide special support for matrix URIs.

Comment: If it helps, I've added a ticket to [scala-uri](https://github.com/theon/scala-uri) to add support for matrix parameters. I may get a chance to do it tomorrow - shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Initial implementation: https://github.com/theon/scala-uri#matrix-parameters . Should help you to build a String url with matrix params.